# How to solve dimensions mismatch error in TensorFlow Autoencoder

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, autoencoder

The code is little long, so I request you to check it on this [Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/13dxp9vn2TO6bt0tXPJ7AatVYPQyXP6oF?usp=sharing) link.

I am building an Auto-Encoder. I worked fine at first, but after adding one more CNN layer, I mean after changing this `layer_filters = [32, 64]` to `layer_filters = [32, 64, 128]` I am getting a dimension error.
This one:

```
ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 32 and 28 for '{{node mean_squared_error/SquaredDifference}} = SquaredDifference[T=DT_FLOAT](autoencoders/decoder/decoder_output/Sigmoid, IteratorGetNext:1)' with input shapes: [32,32,32,1], [32,28,28,1].
```

I think Encoders dimensions and Decoder's dimensions are different due to adding of one more layer. I don't know how to make them same. Can anyone help ?

**EDIT** - @Kaveh has answered this question below, I did what he said, and it worked. So if anyone is visiting this question now. Please note that the notebook that I mention earlier has been updated and has no trace back.

Comment: Please, update with the full error trace.

Comment: The encoder input dimension is `(None, 28, 28, 1)` and the decoder output dimension is `(None, 32, 32, 1)`. You are sending `X_train` to both of them in `autoencoder.fit()`. Same for `X_test`. So, this means that `X_train`, and `X_test` have the dimension of `(None, 32, 32, 1)` which is incompatible with the encoder input dimension `(None, 28, 28, 1)`. TL;DR: as encoder input and decoder output both end are getting same input, their dimensions should be the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Reason:**

Your labels shape `(28,28,3)` is incompatible with the models' output shape `(32,32,3)`, and it is because of divisions by your encoder and decoder.

---

**Source:**

Input shape is `(28,28)` and shape changes with `layer_filters = [32, 64]` is like this:

- encoder: 28 -> 14 -> 7
- decoder:  7 -> 14 -> 28

So, the input and output shape is the same (28) and it works fine. But when you add another layer with 128 neurons (`layer_filters = [32, 64, 128]`) the shape changes is like this:

- encoder: 28 -> 14 -> 7  -> 4
- decoder: 4  -> 8  -> 16 -> 32

Now, 32 and 28 are incompatible and you get error.

---

**Solution:**

Change you layer configuration in such a way that input and output get the same shape. For example:

- You can remove `strides = 2, padding = 'same'` in both decoder and encoder for loop:

  - encoder: 28 -> 26 -> 24 -> 22
  - decoder: 22 -> 24 -> 26 -> 28

or

- Do not add more than 2 Conv2D layers anymore, since in the 3rd layer the shape will be an odd number divided by two. And you can not get back in the same way.

Comment: Can you tell me how did you knew that removing strides and padding will solve this problem ?

Comment: @Hobo I took a look at the full code (link) he has provided, and as I said, with removing this config from layer definition, then shapes will be just subtracted by 2 on each layer (no padding and strides=1), instead of divided by 2.